# How can I make my header image full height?

Tags: html, css, header, web

I have tried adding a white border around the image so that would get cut off instead however it crops the image automatically.

I am hosted by Godaddy and I am using the theme Bento.

My website is http://bentleyandhudson.com

Comment: Full height of the screen ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this code

```
.post-header {
    height: 462px !important;
}
```

to the wp [customizer](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/) or include this code in theme css. You can make it responsive with a couple more @media queries if this is what you're after.

Or else beaver builder can be used to add this very easily.

Comment: Awesome that has fixed the problem, thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: You might need this too 

.site-header.fixed-header {
    height: auto !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to fill the full display height on all screen sizes you could use:

```
.post-header {
    height: 87vh;
}
```

> Notice the [browser compatibility for vh](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).